# Image doesn't exist when trying to add text boxes to an image when creating a gui with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting an error saying that the images doesn't exist. The file location is correct and shows the image when using image.show(). This is the code that I'm trying to use:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

def on_image_click(event):
    # Function to handle the mouse click event on the image
    x, y = event.x, event.y

    # Create a text box at the clicked location
    text = tk.Entry(image_frame, width=20)
    text.place(x=x, y=y)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Labeling of barriers")

# Load the image
image = Image.open(os.path.join("Data", 'maze_layout.png'))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

# Create a frame to display the image
image_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=image.width, height=image.height)
image_frame.pack()

# Create a label to display the image
image_label = tk.Label(image_frame, image=photo)
image_label.pack()

# Bind the mouse click event to the image
image_label.bind("<Button-1>", on_image_click)

root.mainloop()
```

Any ideas?

I tried using  Image.open('Data/maze_layout.png'). I placed the maze_layout file in the same directory and still gives the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [25], in <cell line: 25>()
     22 image_frame.pack()
     24 # Create a label to display the image
---> 25 image_label = tk.Label(image_frame, image=photo)
     26 image_label.pack()
     28 # Bind the mouse click event to the image

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py:3148, in Label.__init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   3130 def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
   3131     """Construct a label widget with the parent MASTER.
   3132 
   3133     STANDARD OPTIONS
   (...)
   3146 
   3147     """
-> 3148     Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py:2572, in BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2570 for k, v in classes:
   2571     del cnf[k]
-> 2572 self.tk.call(
   2573     (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2574 for k, v in classes:
   2575     k.configure(self, v)

TclError: image "pyimage9" doesn't exist
```

Edit: Found the problem as the code was executed multiple times. Thanks for the help!

Comment: please add the absolute Path of the file and the absolute Path of your main.py file to your question. Have you tried to write image = Image.open('Data/maze_layout.png') instead of using os.path.join?

Comment: post the full traceback error message

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I create `Data/maz_layout.png` in the current working directory. Are you aware of the difference between the directory where the script exists and the current working directory?

Comment: That error typically occurs when you've created more than one instance of `Tk()` - each image is associated with a particular instance, and simply won't work with widgets that live in a different instance.  I don't see multiple calls to `Tk()` in the code you posted - either you've left something important out, or you've somehow run the code twice in a single Python interpreter session.